# How to organize a large single repo node.js app

Tags: node.js, npm, structure, package

I have a node.js app using a single git repo, that has various packages. I am trying to make things modularized, and separate.

```
├── common
│   └── formattr
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package.json
│       └── formattr.js
└── providers
    ├── aws
    │   ├── node_modules
    │   └── package.json
    └── google
        ├── node_modules
        └── package.json
```

The problem I am running into is that when somebody clones the app, they have to recurse into each package direction and manually run `npm install`. Additionally, there is lots of wasted resources and duplication, since the package `aws` might use `npm install request` but so does the `google` package. Right now, they both store independ versions.

Finally, there is this problem as well:

```
// Inside of the aws package, I need formattr. This makes me cry inside.
let format = require('../../common/formattr/formattr');
```

What is the recommended pattern and structure?

Comment: Is there a reason you put all this into a single git repo? If you split it out, you can still use the first repo as a dependency in the second one. Even without publishing to `npm`.

Comment: Want to use a monolithic single directory structure.

Comment: But why? What's stopping you from splitting it up and making your life easier?

Comment: The single repo pattern actually has a lot of benefits (Google, Facebook) do it.